# Strange sql query with avg

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to query my db with this:

```
SELECT ar.email, tr.trackid, al.albumtitle, al.albumid, al.publishingdate, tr.genre, tr.tracktitle, ar.artistname, tr.reproductions, CEIL(AVG(co.rating)) AS 'media' 
FROM tsn_tracks tr, tsn_albums al, tsn_artists ar, tsn_comments co 
WHERE al.email=ar.email AND tr.albumid=al.albumid  tr.trackid = co.trackid
GROUP BY tr.trackid
ORDER BY al.publishingdate desc 
LIMIT 0, 20
```

I will explain the scheme very quickly: i want to retrive the first 20 songs in order of publishing date (from the most recent) with all the different attributes, in particualr, users can write comments about a track and leave a vote (from 1 to 5) in their comments, in my query I want to show the vote avg of each song, but when a song haven't recived any comment, it doesn't appear in the result set (beacause of the "tr.trackid = co.trackid"). I have tried in many different ways but without solving the problem. I want the my query will give me a particular value (for example 0) when a song doesn't have any comments.

Sorry for my english!

Comment: Use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of gluing your join up in the `WHERE` clause...

Comment: Add table structure and sample data as well to get required result quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Using JOINs instead of using everthing in the FROM and WHERE will allow you to use LEFT JOINS.  This means that a row will be retrieved even if the the table (notionally) on the right doesn't have a matching record.

```
SELECT ar.email, tr.trackid, al.albumtitle, al.albumid, 
        al.publishingdate, tr.genre, tr.tracktitle, ar.artistname,
        tr.reproductions, CEIL(AVG(co.rating)) AS 'media' 
    FROM tsn_tracks tr
    JOIN tsn_albums al on tr.albumid=al.albumid 
    JOIN tsn_artists ar ON al.email=ar.email
    LEFT JOIN tsn_comments co ON tr.trackid = co.trackid
    GROUP BY tr.trackid
    ORDER BY al.publishingdate desc 
    LIMIT 0, 20
```

Comment: I knew about the join function but i'have never used it. Thank you so much!

Comment: You will need to check if getting the average on no records (null) will fit in with how you want.  You can use `avg(COALESCE(co.rating,0))` to make it 0.